# Convert C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have  2 functions in C++ which need to be converted to C#. Below are the details of the functions

### C++

```
void MyClass::GetArg(string argument, int minError, string* arg1, string* arg2, 
string* arg3, string* arg4, string* arg5)
{
      if(arg1 != null) *arg1 = GetArg(argument, 1, minError)
      if(arg2 != null) *arg2 = GetArg(argument, 2, minError)
      if(arg3 != null) *arg3 = GetArg(argument, 3, minError)
      if(arg4 != null) *arg4 = GetArg(argument, 4, minError)
      if(arg5 != null) *arg5 = GetArg(argument, 5, minError) 
}

string MyClass::GetArg(string argument, int argNum, int minError)
{
     //Whatever logic
}
```

And I am seeing function call as

```
GetArg(argString, 3, &v1, &v2, &v3);
```

The question I have here is, I am not seeing any overloaded function which takes 5 arguments. Are those additional arguments, arg4 and arg5 optional?

I have created a similar function in C# as below

```
public string GetArg(string argument, int argNum, int minError)
{
     //Logic goes here
}
```

I have converted  GetArg(argString, 3, &v1, &v2, &v3) into 3 separate function calls as below

```
string v1 = GetArg(argString, 1, 3);
string v2 = GetArg(argString, 2, 3);
string v3 = GetArg(argString, 3, 3);
```

I am not sure what is the impact of converting as above as I have very minimum knowledge in C++. I would appreciate if anyone could show me a better way of converting this.

Comment: In the c++ code did you intend for all of the `if` statements to have `arg1` or was it meant to be `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, `...`?

Comment: You have to look at the function declaration to check for optional argument values.

Comment: @quasiverse, it's my bad. I have edited the question.

Comment: one thing to note is you can use managed cpp to ensure c# calling if that is a source of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your C++ code won't compile.  All argument sare required in C++, unless you specifically make them optional (by using an = default) or by using the variable arguments mechanism leftover from C

As such, it's impossible to make C# do the same thing, since the code you posted is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass parameters by reference and use .NET framework 4

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MyClass {
    public string GetArg(string argument, int minError, ref string arg1, ref string arg2, ref string arg3, [Optional] ref string arg4, [Optional] ref string arg5)
    {
          if(arg1 != null) arg1 = GetArg(argument, 1, minError);
          if(arg1 != null) arg2 = GetArg(argument, 2, minError);
          if(arg1 != null) arg3 = GetArg(argument, 3, minError);
          if(arg1 != null) arg4 = GetArg(argument, 4, minError);
          if(arg1 != null) arg5 = GetArg(argument, 5, minError);
    }
}
```

call

```
GetArg(argString, 3, v1, v2, v3);
```

Comment: This code throws a syntax error. It requires all the 5 reference parameters to be passed.

Comment: @AlanB - And your original code would have the same error in C++